# Azure Data Factory toTime Format and Output just hh:mm:ss

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have hour column with nvarchar format ... like example column is

```
14:45:56
20:03:25
etc
```

we know in ADF have toDate and ToTimeStamp to create expression in derived column for example:

I have try

```
toTimestamp(toString((currentUTC()+ hours(7))),'HH:mm:ss')
```

but the result is null when i'm trying to review. many big thanks to post the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the time format both inside toString() and toTimestamp():

toTimestamp(toString(currentUTC()+ hours(7),'HH:mm:ss'),'HH:mm:ss')

Comment: thanks for your answer .. i will try ..